# Unifying exceptions format in Java

Tags: java, error-handling, exception, try-catch

I am writing a Java app and **I'd like to have an unified format** for my exceptions. Something like:

```
try{
//...
} catch(Exception e){
   log(clazz.getSimpleName() + ":" + e.getMessage() + ":" + e);
}
```

This means that every exception in the logs will present the following aspect, roughly:

```
<class_name>.java: <message>: <exception>
```

I can always write a '`ExceptionDealer`' class with a `static` method that logs the exception receiving the class name and the exception instance itself, but I am not sure if this would be an overkill.

Is there any elegant way of doing this?

Comment: You can use some Logging Library like log4j, slf4j or logback

Comment: Seems as elegant as it can be to me, Sara. `e` will likely have to be processed to actually get the stack trace inside of your `log()` method, or you may just end up with an object reference

Comment: @SilverNak I am using log4j actually, but the question is different: I want to ensure a format in my exceptions.

Comment: Whatever you do ***don't*** just `+ e` -- The original exception MUST be chained or you will have trouble debugging problems later and whoever has to maintain your system will curse your name in eternity.

Comment: @j.seashell thanks

Comment: @JimGarrison Sorry, could you please explain it further? Shouldn't e.toString() be called?

Comment: `Throwable#toString()` -- which is the method invoked -- does not format the entire stack trace.  You are throwing away a lot of information.

Comment: Just enforce your message style in each catch. What if it needs to change for one of the exceptions. Also try to avoid checked exceptions as much as possible.

Comment: Something else you can do it get data from the stack trace. Quite often i see NullPointerExceptions in logs like this with no idea where they came from.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw a custom exception and log inside the constructor.

```
public class CustomException() extends Exception {

  public CustomException(Exception ex) {
    super(ex);
    log(ex.getStackTrace[0].getClassName() + ":" + ex.getMessage());
  }
}
```

And then in your `catch`

```
} catch(Exception e){
   throw new CustomException(e);
}
```

Comment: This may yield different behaviour, since you have to ensure that `CustomException` is thrown always. Otherwise you might habe an Exception in your log which never was thrown. (I know, this is a rather uncommon case, but think of someone who saves the exception in a variable rather than throwing it immediately)

Comment: I would try to avoid all the catching and rethrowing.

Comment: @SilverNak We could use unit tests to check log's content against CustomException throwings.